# Using an exposed object as value or helper in Express.js with jade templating?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm exposing (for testing purposes) an object and a named function:

```
var express = require('express')
  , expose  = require('express-expose')
  , app     = express();

// ...

// Expose with 'utils' namespace, default 'javascript' buffer
app.expose({ foo: 'bar' }, 'utils');

// Expose named function with 'funcs' buffer
app.expose(function foo() { return 'bar'; }, 'funcs');
```

JavaScript variables are created just fine:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        title
        // Buffer 'javascript'
        script!= javascript
        // Buffer 'funcs'
        script!= funcs
    body
```

Output:

```
<!-- Buffer 'javascript'-->
<script>
    window.utils = window.utils || {};
    utils["foo"] = "bar";
</script>
<!-- Buffer 'funcs'-->
<script>
    function foo() { return 'bar'; }
</script>
```

But I'd like to access both object `{ foo: 'bar' }` and `function foo() { return 'bar'; }` from inside Jade. According to [`express.expose`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose/tree/master/examples) both are available in Jade... but where?

Comment: As far as I [can see](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose/blob/master/lib/express-expose.js#L60), they aren't exposed as proper JS objects to Jade, just as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can add locals to your jade templates application wide by adding them to app.locals.

```
app.locals.foo = function foo() { return 'bar'; }
```